# Combinatorics , complexity, unclear easy inequality in a sum with combination numbers

Tags: combinatorics, summation, combinations

How can I see on page 108 [here](https://www.math.ias.edu/csdm/files/Archives/11-12/rimpagliazzo_relativized_separation_of_worst_case.pdf) , in the proof of lemma 4,

that from -6th line follows -5th line, i.e. how do I justify that $\leq$ there?

I got so far: if the following holds, for $8K < N$ and $T < K$, 
then I would believe the inequality in question:

${K!}^2(N-K)!/{(K-L)!^2(N-K+L)!} \leq K^2LN^L/(N-K)^{2L}$

Any suggestion how to understand the example is welcome.

Comment: Do write out the actual question here.